# create XWPFDocument from custom XML?

Tags: java, apache-poi, openxml

I was hoping to use org.apache.poi.xwpf.converter.xhtml.XHTMLConverter to create some xhtml from client's database of OOXML files. Unfortunately, these files are stored in parts, and I can reconstruct them only with either string contactenation or XML manipulation.

Bottom line, I have a string/XML and I need to construct a XWPFDocument from it. How to do it?

Kindest Regards